# Doom Emacs : Creating project using dired not working

Tags: dired, doom, projectile

I'm a new to emacs. So I just try to learn by using it.

And What I'm trying to do is just making simple project.

I make a directory in dired using `+` command.

And inside that directory I create `.projectile` file.

If I know correctly, when I revisit that directory, that directory should be registered in project by `projectile`.

But It wasn't registered. Also not manually registered by `SPC-p-a` command
( In this case, seems to registered because I can see when I do `SPC-SPC`, But It does not do project things like `SPC-p-p` to show inside files etc ... )

And I made exactly same directory ( and `.projectile` file ) outside emacs and opened in emacs. and It works like I expected ( visit and registered as project ).

**Question : What makes them work differently?**
( But It can be solved by invalidate cache of that directory )

---

For better explanation, This is what I did in order.

1. Open emacs.
2. make directory using `dired`
3. and make empty .projectile file in that directory
4. and goto that directory
5. do tests in that directory ,

- `SPC-SPC` to open file list. -> not working (just show project list)
- `SPC-p-a` to register that directory as project. -> seems working ( registered in project list) but can't do project things like `SPC-SPC` in that directory to list files
  But works fine when I create directory and `.projectile` outside emacs and do test in emacs.